# Zend Framework - How to Properly set Include Path?

Tags: php, zend-framework, apache2

I'm trying to install TheStudio application which was apparently written using Zend Framework.  My test server is running Ubuntu 12.04 and my application directory is stored in /home

My error log is stating

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'usr/share/php/libzend-frameworkphp/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'   
  (include_path='.:../library:../application/db:../application/models:../application/utils:../application/views/helpers:../application') in /home/application/config/config.php on line 22
```

Line 22 of config.php states:

```
require_once '/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
```

The include path is as follows:

```
define('PS',        PATH_SEPARATOR);
define('DS',        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR',  dirname('home'));

// Modify include path
$paths = '.' . PS . '..' . DS . 'library'
         . PS . '..' . DS . 'application' . DS . 'db'
         . PS . '..' . DS . 'application' . DS . 'models'
         . PS . '..' . DS . 'application' . DS . 'utils'
         . PS . '..' . DS . 'application' . DS . 'views' . DS . 'helpers'
         . PS . '..' . DS . 'application';
ini_set("include_path", $paths);
```

How should I modify the path statement to target the files located in /home directory?  Are there other adjustments that should be made in order to resolve the above error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include Zend Framework libraries in my domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414341/how-do-i-include-zend-framework-libraries-in-my-domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/share/php/libzend-frameworkphp` is the default installation path for the Zend Framework Ubuntu package, so it seems this application is assuming that will be there. `sudo apt-get install zend-framework` should solve that problem.

I would say it's bad practice to include the full path on a `require_once` call, and there are way too many include paths being defined on your third code example (which I assume is from the app?).

Comment: I've installed ZF via apt-get.  I confirmed that's the directory location.  How can I shorten the require_once statement to conform to better practice?

Comment: Is config.php your code or part of the app? `/usr/share/php/libzend-framework` should be on your include path so you should just do `require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';`

Comment: Config.php is in the application/config directory.